# Regex not replacing as Expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a node script that I use to build my vue project. I need to update some vue source links from:

```
:src="\'./src/img/\'
```

to

```
:src="\'./img/\'
```

My code to do this is:

```js
const regEx6 = /:src="'.\/src\/img/gi;
const regEx7 = /^:src=(?:"(?:\\\'\.\/src\/img\/\\|\'\.\/src\/img\/)\')?$/gi;

if (regEx6.test(fileContents || regEx7.test(fileContents))) {
  console.log(
    `Vue Directive :src found. Will try updating link. ${warning}`
  );
}

if (
  regEx6.test(fileContents) ||
  regEx7.test(fileContents)
) {
  let distFile = fileContents
    .replace(regEx6, `:src="'./img`)
    .replace(regEx7, `src="\\'./img/\\'`);
```

I have verified it works in a regex tester ok and yet after running build no change is seen. And also the .test I have in for the expressions is not consoling. Any idea's on why my regex's are failing would be most appreciated...

Updated code:

```
 if (regEx6.test(fileContents) || regEx7.test(fileContents)) {
      console.log(
        `Vue Directive :src found. Will try updating link. ${warning}`
      );
    }
```

Update: I was using regex generator I found online wrong. Here is regex expresion I needed

```
const regEx7 = /:src="\\\'\.\/src\/img\/\\\'/gi;
```

Now works as expected. Thanks...

Comment: Your parentheses are misplaced in the first `if`. It should be like the second `if`.

Comment: You're missing the `}` at the end of the second `if`.

Comment: Why do you need two `if` statements with the same condition? Just put the `console.log` at the beginning of the the second one.

Comment: Seems like the usage of a decent project IDE with a global ctrl+r would solve this a lot faster than writing logic...

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
const regEx7 = /:src="\\'\.\/src\/img\/\\'/gi;
.replace(regEx7, "src="\\'./img/\\'");
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/RTW9Vv/1/). No need escaping `'` in the regex.

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :src="                   ':src="'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  src                      'src'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  img                      'img'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  '                        '\''
```

Comment: Thanks. Regex not my forte. I found an online generator that did the trick. But not as good as a human:)